# Can't access some items in XML using Azure Logic App

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I've been trying to parse XML with a given structure and subsequently load all the data into a database using Azure Logic App.
I read that you need to convert the XML to JSON to perform any operations but I've been having issues with accessing some of the items from the XML.
Here is a XML with similar structure to get the idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schedule>
  <ID>449c</ID>
  <TimeSeries>
    <ID>34244</ID>
    <version>1</version>
    <domain>bb</domain>
    <Period>
      <timeInterval>
        <start>2020-02-12T23:00Z</start>
        <end>2020-02-13T23:00Z</end>
      </timeInterval>
      <Point>
        <position>1</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>2</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>3</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>4</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>5</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>6</position>
        <quantity>290.8</quantity>
      </Point>
    </Period>
  </TimeSeries>
  <TimeSeries>
    <ID>34245</ID>
    <domain>aa</domain>
    <version>1</version>
    <Period>
      <timeInterval>
        <start>2020-02-12T23:00Z</start>
        <end>2020-02-13T23:00Z</end>
      </timeInterval>
      <Point>
        <position>1</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>2</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>3</position>
        <quantity>30</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>4</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>5</position>
        <quantity>890</quantity>
      </Point>
      <Point>
        <position>6</position>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
      </Point>
    </Period>
  </TimeSeries></Schedule>
```

I was able to transform it to JSON and then parsing it but it says that TimeSeries are null. I need to save all the positions with their associated values into a database.
Could anyone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Any update now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what expression you used to get the `TimeSeries` value , I will show in my test how to get the json data.

Firstly I use blob to get the xml file content, the parse to json. I use `json(xml(body('Get_blob_content')))` to parse the xml to json. Then use `outputs('compose')['Schedule']['TimeSeries']` to get the array value.

[image]

[image]

And if you want to get more specific value, the expression will be like `outputs('compose')['Schedule']['TimeSeries'][0]['Period']['timeInterval']['start']`.

[image]

And more if your data format is fixed, you could use parse json action to parse json, then you will be able to get the dynamic content.

[image]